# Converting Java SSLSocket to unencrypted Socket

Tags: java, jsse

I want to take an existing SSL connection that has already exchanged sensitive information using encrypted connection, and switch it back to using the socket unencrypted. I am using *SSLServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket* which actually listens for requests from client. Now after doing *ServerSocket.accept*, I get *SSLSocket* which I use to do an initial exchange of some sensitive information. Once I am done with this exchange I want to use the same socket in an unencrypted manner (like a normal Socket). Is it at all possible?

On the net I get responses that I can use *SSLSocketFactory.createSocket* and set *autoClose* to false. I am not sure how that can help, given that *SSLServerSocketFactory* doesn't have this parameter.

Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `SSLServerSocketFactory`. Use ordinary `ServerSocket` to listen and create an ordinary server-side `Socket` and give that to [SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Socket,InputStream,boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket-java.net.Socket-java.io.InputStream-boolean-) with autoClose=false and if applicable consumed=null. Reading the linked javadoc explains how this workds. After ending the SSL part of the connection, continue using the `Socket` as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. I have a question though. Now that SSL socket is being initialized post accept each time, will it have any performance impact?

Comment: @Prabhat I doubt it; the usual/simpler case `sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept()` actually does the same steps (create `SSLSocketImpl` with side=server, `accept` on the underlying socket, and `SSLSocketImpl.doneConnect()`) although in a different order, which moves a few nanoseconds of initialization before the accept. But the hugely dominant costs in either case are the actual handshake (both the network comms for the handshake packets, and the crypto to do the handshake) and those are identical.